# adjust line numbers so PHP code is not counted in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, php, notepad++, line

Is there a way to jump over code blocks so that line numbers adjust and take out that section.

Example - I have a code block from lines 1-88 that are php.  I would like those lines to not be considered when notepad++ counts lines.  Therefore line 1 would be line 89.

I have some php code in my page with javascript and when I look at the error with chrome developer tools the line of the error is thrown off by this because chrome developer is not seeing the php but notepad++ is....

Any suggestions on other editors with this feature, plugins, or just a general best practice for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: put your js in an external file and call it with a <script> tag ? I don't know of a editor that would selectively count lines when reading a mixed-language file

Comment: I think the best thing to do in this case is to separate your PHP  code and JS code to different files

Comment: Think about it again. You're taking for granted that PHP code does not produce output, ever. If you want to debug stuff properly you need to reorganise your application design and separate stuff in files (HTML, JavaScript, CSS...). In any case, no idea about Chrome but many browsers allows to click on errors and will display the offending source code, wherever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much more better solution is to externalize your javascript script in a file. With this "trick" (well not realy a trick, everyone use it) chrome will show you the line from the file where your JS script is stored.

Add this to your HTML/PHP file :

```
<script src="myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And move your JS code to `myscripts.js`

Comment: I completely forgot about this... this particular file has been growing and growing so I guess I just did not expect to need to separate things.  Thanks for the answer so quick!